# Convert mysql_* to PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a program using PHP and trying to store data into Local Server Xampp, but whenever i run my php script using this url:

```
        http://127.0.0.1/test.php
```

Getting error message: **{"StatusID":"0","Error":"Cannot save data!"}**

Please someone help me in this how can i make it useful for me, please check below PHP Script:

```
    <?php

$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_error($ObjConnect);

$objDB = mysql_select_db("registration_login");
mysql_error($ObjDB);

$strUsername = $_POST["sUsername"];
$strPassword = $_POST["sPassword"];
$strName = $_POST["sName"];
$strEmail = $_POST["sEmail"];
$strTel = $_POST["sTel"];

/*** Insert ***/
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO member (Username,Password,Name,Email,Tel)
VALUES (
'".$strUsername."',
'".$strPassword."',
'".$strName."',
'".$strEmail."',
'".$strTel."'
)
";

$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
mysql_error($ObjQuery);

if(!$objQuery)
{
$arr["Status"] = "0";
$arr["Message"] = "Cannot Save Data!";

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}
else
{
$arr["Status"] = "1";
$arr["Message"] = "Register Successfully!";

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
}

mysql_close($objConnect);

?>
```

**Note:** I have created **registration_login** database and **member** table under this DB..

Comment: Add some logging or something to capture the return value of `mysql_error()` if an error occurred. No debugging is possible otherwise. And please don't use `mysql_*` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the error reported by mysql or log it somewhere?

> $objConnect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

You forgot to check the return the return value to see if this was successful - if it failed, the reason is in mysql_error()

> $objDB = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

You forgot to check the return the return value to see if this was successful - if it failed, the reason is in mysql_error()

> $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

At least this time you check the return value - but you don't check what the error was.

BTW your script is wide open to SQL injection.

> Convert mysql_* to PDO

What has that got to do with your post?